# Cumulative Distribution Function of the skewed generalized error distribution for qq-plot

Tags: r, visualization, numerical-integration, cdf

I´m trying to calculate the cumulative distribution function of the skewed generalized error distribution with the probability density function from Theodossiou([http://www.mfsociety.org/modules/modDashboard/uploadFiles/journals/MJ~0~p1a4fjq38m1k2p45t6481fob7rp4.pdf](http://www.mfsociety.org/modules/modDashboard/uploadFiles/journals/MJ%7E0%7Ep1a4fjq38m1k2p45t6481fob7rp4.pdf)):

[image]

And in R it looks like this:

```
psi <- -0.09547862
m <- 0.1811856
g <- -0.1288893
d <- 0.8029088

c <- (2/(1+exp(-g)))-1
p <- exp(psi)

y <- function(x) ((d**(1-(1/d)))/(2*p))*gamma(1/d)**(-1)*exp(-(1/d)*((abs(x-m)**d)/((1+sign(x-m)*c)**(d)*p**(d))))
```

I do this is to fit the skewed generalized error distribution to my data and assess the distributions fit to my data by creating a qq-plot. So now I need to calculate the cumulative distribution function and then the inverse cdf. For the inverse cdf I plan to use the inversion-function from the GofKernel-Package. But for this I need the cdf. Is there anyway to calculate that with numerical integration in R?

Comment: The cdf for the skewed generalized error distribution is already implemented in R in the fGarch package with the function `psged`. Is there a reason why you don't want to use that?

Comment: The package fGarch contains a function called dsged. I suspect you are showing the same function. Can you confirm?

Comment: The pdf and cdf in fGarch are from  Fernández and steel I think. And I dont get how They calculate them. But Im not sure whether it is the same.

Comment: Sorry I complete forgot to mention that is use the method from Theodossiou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a cumulative function via integration you can pass the x-values to a function that integrates from a suitable extreme low value to an upper limit that is `x`

```
 # First look at the density function
 plot( y(x) ~ x )


 cum <- sapply(x, function(x) integrate(y,-10, x)$value )
 plot( cum ~ x)
 
 # So the inverse is just `x`  as a function of `cum`
 plot( x ~ cum)
```

Comment: Tank you thank you thank you!! Just to make sure Im getting it right. So my Data is stored in xsD1 so I have to replace every x in your solution with my xsD1 right. And another question Im trying to add a line like qqline but I made it with the 0.25 and 0.75 quantile from cum and xsD1, is this approach also right?

Comment: To make a qqplot you need two sets of information. One needs to be the theoretical quantiles which is what you now can compute but the other is a set of independent observations possibly drawn from that distribution and the Q plot is a display of how well they agree. You have not presented any data.

Answer (score -1):

In general, if you want to estimate the cumulative distribution function, use the function ecdf as follows:

```
x <- seq(-10,10,0.1)
Fn <- ecdf(y(x))
plot(Fn)
```

If you want to visualize how two data sets are similar, use qqplot as follows:

```
y1 <- y(x)            # from your function
y2 <- rnorm(100)      # some generic data
qqplot(y1, y2)        # if the two data sets are from the same 
                      # distribution, you should see a straight line
```

Comment: Thank you very much but how can I implement this to my function?

Comment: Note the line Fn <- ecdf (y(x))    y(x) is the function you defined.  Generate a sequence of x's and you are good to go. In other words, add those lines below your code.

Comment: @YLC: I think you need to review the use of ecdf. It's supposed to take a set of observations which is NOT what a density function provides.